Why is "domesticate" the answer to “Tame comedies and West End” production?
Clue is “Tame comedies and West End production.”
Solution is “domesticate” which is probably an anagram of “comedies” and something else but I can’t work out what.

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question? For example, if this is from a newspaper, please note the name of the paper and the edition (day/week/month)

The "something else" is "tat". Could the clue be "Tame comedies at West End production" instead?

@MOehm still only gives you one of the 't's though. I'm guessing "West End production" simplifies to "tat" but I don't know why...

@InBedded16. I know. My suggestion is: rot13(nantenz ("cebqhpgvba") bs PBZRQVNA + NG + (jrf)G ("Jrfg Raq")).

@MOehm okay sure, I do see how that would work in that case. However when I search up the clue online, there are crossword answer databases that show it as "and" and not "at" so there must be a reason why it works as is.

@InBedded16 I've seen some of these entries, too. Some suggest that the answer is "domesticated", where "and" is part of the anagram, and that there is a mistake in the clue.
